# Sharp, Pnpm on windows The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: node.js, sharp, pnpm, node-canvas

I am trying to run an application that is dependent on sharp. I get this error when I try to run the application.
I use pnpm as package manager
I did a lot of digging around this. But unable to find the solution. Please help.
[image]

Comment: I found this link on github. It is by the creator of sharp, I think.
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2125#issuecomment-653783908
I am unable to understand, what is to be done here. TBH, I am new at all this. still learning.